# Using MySQL WorkBench to recover a .BAK file

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am extremely new to MySQL and databases. My objective is convert a .BAK file to a database. So far I have downloaded MySQL Workbench. From there I am lost as to the process of converting the .BAK file to a database.

Any and all help would be welcomed

Comment: `.bak` is usually used for all kinds of backup files. What makes you think this file contains a database script?

Comment: I know that there exists a database script in the .BAK file due to the circumstances under which the file was given to me. It should just contain inventory items for a basic neighborhood store

Comment: So this is a DB dump file? If so, rename it to `.sql` and use the `Restore` section in the Admin part to load it into your server.

Answer (score 1):

I'm probably late but I think I can help since I'm encountering the same problem.
A .bak file is in few words a MS SQL database backup file, which can be opened and managed with no problem with the Microsoft tools.

You are (I guess) trying to convert the .bak (MSSQL) into .sql (MySQL). I'm trying this same thing btw.
I found this web and so far this worked for some tables:

https://www.silicongadget.com/software/database/import-mssql-bak-files-to-mysql/2955/

Oh btw in point 9 of the tutorial linked, the migration tool can be found clicking "Database" (in the toolbar top left thing) > "Migration Wizard". Just to clear since it's not explained in the tutorial and unexperienced people can get stuck.

If you have any question let me know and I will **try** to solve it.

Best of luck!

Comment: 20231101: Link is invalid. Also, site appears invalid.